# How can I (easily) import/show Nexrad radar images from the last 24 hours in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I am using Iowa State map services to provide weather radar images of the USA as it is done here: http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/ogc/googlemaps_v3.html ("the example").

```
<script>
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.5, -95.5),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        mapOptions);
    
    var tileNEX = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
            return "https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime(); 
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity:0.60,
        name : 'NEXRAD',
        isPng: true
    });

    
    var goes = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
            return "https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/goes-east-vis-1km-900913/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime(); 
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity:0.60,
        name : 'GOES East Vis',
        isPng: true
    });

    map.overlayMapTypes.push(null); // create empty overlay entry
    map.overlayMapTypes.setAt("0",goes);
    map.overlayMapTypes.push(null); // create empty overlay entry
    map.overlayMapTypes.setAt("1",tileNEX);

    
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

This shows a tiled version of the last weather radar image of continental USA, which works perfectly fine. Now, I would like to be able to request radar images from the last 24 hours, just like that.

There are ways to easily fetch up to the last 50 minutes of radar images, as described here: https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/ogc/, for example using `nexrad-n0q-900913-m40m` (40 minutes ago). There are mentions of historical radar data images, for example here: http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/GIS/ridge.phtml but I can't wrap my head around how to use it in a similar manner as in 'the example' given above.

In 'the example' the radar images for the entire US is fetched but it seems like in all other API:s you can only get it for specific radar stations.

How should I go about to get last 24h historical radar image data in tiles, such as in 'the example'? For example, the corresponding radar image at 4 hours ago.

Changing the timestamp at the end of the getTileUrl to a previous timestamp doesn't work. I don't understand how to use WMS (is that the only way?). My only thought of solving this is to save the tiled PNG:s to a server every 5 minutes, and call my own server - but there has to be a better solution.

Comment: @googlemaps/ogc has options for WMS https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/ogc

Answer (score 1):

It turns out one can use the following url to access previous radar images:

```
https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/ridge::USCOMP-N0Q-" + formatTimestamp() + "/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png
```

where formatTimestamp() is a timestamp like yyyymmddhhmm '202201201345' where the last minute needs to be modulo 5, i.e. 5 or 0.